# Setting y-axis labels to be in scientific notation

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot, bigdata

An issue I am having right now is that when I subplot several plots onto a figure, some of them are plotted with the y axis in scientific notation, and others are not. It makes the plots look somewhat ugly and inconsistent, for example:

[image]

I have tried several solutions I found online and got really strange results (none of them did what I want to happen).

I am creating the subplots like this:

```
for i = 1:size(clusters, 2) % for each cluster in clusters (a cell array).
    cluster = cell2mat(clusters(i)); % get the matrix stored in the element
    nRows = size(cluster,1); % number of rows in the matrix
    x = 1:nRows; % x axis (row index of matrix)
    figure(2) 
    subplot(3,2,i);
    plot(x, cluster'); % plot the graph
end
end
```

Why is the y label in scientific notation for some of the subplots but not for others? Is there a way around this? Also whilst I'm here, each cluster corresponds to a matrix - if this is the case then what exactly does the y axis represent?

Highly grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it is not the difference of formatting but the different number of digits that makes MATLAB to compact numbers in some of the plots.

**But**, If by scientific notation, you mean scientific formatting of numbers then, you can achieve it easily. Take a look at the following example:

```
x = 1:10000;
y = 1000*log10(x);
plot(x,y)
xlab = linspace(1,10000,6);
ylab = linspace(1,4000,6);
set(gca,'XTick',xlab)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%1.2e\n',xlab))
set(gca,'YTick',ylab)
set(gca,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%1.2e\n',ylab))
```

[image]

Here in the left you see how normally [MATLAB] formats the numbers in a plot, and in the right the formatting done by my example.